# Enabling Notes and Attachments after custom object creation

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, attachment

When I first started our custom object *Request_for_System_Change*, I didn’t check the box to allow Add Notes and Attachments – and according to the documentation [SALESFOREC.com - Fields for Defining Custom Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_objectcreate.htm&language=en%20:)
 this option **is only available when creating new custom objects**

so is there an Apex or VF way to do this?

Comment: My first thought here is to raise a case and see if they can just do this for you.

Comment: @JesseMilburn: you mean with SalesForce support / Customer Services?

Comment: Yes. [here](https://help.salesforce.com). I don't see any other way around this, as the object is already created. I would log a case and see if they can activate that for you from their end.

Comment: I looked at [How to create the clone of Custom Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008tr3IAA) and I may just try to clone the object, then hack all the VF and Apex code with Find-Replace...

Comment: It will almost certainly be less work to contact SFDC support and see if they can enable the feature first.

Comment: I would highly suggest contacting support prior to doing a hack, it may be as simple as them just flipping a switch for you. I would like to know if they could do it for you or not as well.

Comment: And whatever you find out from them will probably be the answer to this question. So please answer it in case someone else comes across this in the future. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This checkbox simply saves you the trouble of having to drag the Notes and Attachments related list onto the page layout.

Here I forget to do this on creating my new object. Oh no!

[image: No notes and attachments! Shoot...]

If I go to the UI for my new object, sure enough, no notes and attachments related list.

[image: Sure enough...an empty related list!]

Go to your page layout, find the related lists. In there you will find the related list for "Notes and Attachments".

[image: Oh...you mean the related list is ready to use?]

Drag that onto the related list part of the page layout.

[image]

You're all set. No worries.

[image: Now I can add notes and attachments. Woo hoo!]

Comment: I have this on all 3 of my layouts (one for each of 3 record types) but when I open the standard *New* page there is no **Notes and Attachments** section...

Comment: I don't think related lists show up ever on the `new` or `edit` record page. You only see related lists once the record is saved and in `view` mode.

Comment: I can't just do a smiley...not enough characters. :-)

Comment: Well now I feel stupid, live and learn. Great simple answer! :)

Comment: I admit I cringed a bit at the "call support" comments. But no...I have explained that hundreds of times. You're not alone. Surprised it's the first time it ever came up in SFSE, TBH. :-)